# Help setting up phoenix miner on Ubuntu 12.04 - getting a seg fault

Tags: ubuntu, phoenix

I'm roughly following [this](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?PHPSESSID=a1bbdf0e554e3c8b8f2d015ffcd972e7&topic=9239.0;all) guide. The only big difference is I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 and I used the latest version of the ATI Drivers. (I have the same cards as the guide, 2x HD5830's)

When I try running the miner, I'm getting a seg fault.
Here's the exact command I'm running:

```
./phoenix.py -u http://mineruser@miner0:password0@mine2.btcguild.com:8332 -k phatk DEVICE=0
```

I'm not sure if this will help but here is the output from `DISPLAY=:0 sudo fglrxinfo`

```
display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: ATI Radeon HD 5800 Series
OpenGL version string: 4.2.11627 Compatibility Profile Context



display: :0  screen: 1
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: ATI Radeon HD 5800 Series
OpenGL version string: 4.2.11627 Compatibility Profile Context
```

Comment: I "solved" my issue by reinstalling 12.04 and used the catalyst 11.11 drivers and cgminer. Roughly followed [this](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Gw7YPYgMgNNU42skibULbJJUx_suP_CpjSEdSi8_z9U/edit) guide.

Comment: You can use `sgminer` too - https://github.com/veox/sgminer/issues?milestone=2&state=open using this tutorial http://askubuntu.com/q/434591/95857